# How to get the installation link of apk file on Google play

Tags: android, url, google-play

I want to get the location of the apk on the google market . Is that possible ?

**Edit**

I want to restrict the internet(Router) to install only the application,  I don't want to allow the internet to open the other websites. If I use the application link, when installing the application the installation link is different from the application link, so this link will be blocked.

How to allow the internet router to open only the application apk file.?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the url to the apk file itself stored on Google's servers if that is what you are after. This would be for security reasons and also because there probably isn't just one copy of it (redundancy, distributed servers, scaling etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the installation URl. Following points taken care my Market

- What if the application is paid on?
- Counters How many downloads?
- Device's Support(Screen or Apis)
- Country support

But you can get your application's URL on Market, This is the link `"market://details?id=" + YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME`

*Note: This thing generally for Application rating within app.*